# QML: ListView and toolbar with "Back" button

Tags: qt, listview, toolbar, qml

I'm trying to figure this out a while and I'm stuck. So there I have some simple ListView with expanding delegates and a toolbar with "back" button above it. This what I want is to be able to redirect onClick action from button to currently expanded element (mainly to collapse it).

I'll post some code after I'll clean it, but for now this has to be it (not working example):

```
Rectangle {
    id: main
    Toolbar {
        id: myTolbar
        Button{ id: backButton }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: myDelegate
        ListElement { option: "OptionA" }
        /// .... etc.
    }

    ListView {
        id: myList
        model: dataModel
        delegate: myDelegate
    }
    Component {
        id: myDelegate
        Text{ text: option }
        states: State{
            name: 'details'
            PropertyChanges { } //some property magic
        }

        MouseArea {
            onClick: state='details'
            //!!!! here I need some help - how to "tell" backButton 
            //to change state of currently shown item back to default state ('')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible working solution

```
// import QtQuick 1.0 // to target S60 5th Edition or Maemo 5
import QtQuick 1.1
import com.nokia.symbian 1.1  // For ToolBar and ToolButton; Replace with whatever you want

Rectangle {
    id: main
    property int curSelectedIndex: -1

    ToolBar {
        id: myTolbar
        anchors.top: parent.top
        ToolButton {
            id: backButton
            text: "Back"
            onClicked: {
                if (main.curSelectedIndex != -1) {
                    dataModel.setProperty(main.curSelectedIndex, "selected", false)
                    main.curSelectedIndex = -1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: dataModel
        ListElement { option: "OptionA"; selected: false }
        ListElement { option: "OptionB"; selected: false }
        ListElement { option: "OptionC"; selected: false }
        /// .... etc.
    }

    ListView {
        id: myList
        anchors {top: myTolbar.bottom; bottom: parent.bottom; right: parent.right; left: parent.left }
        model: dataModel
        delegate: myDelegate
    }
    Component {
        id: myDelegate
        Item {
            height: txOption.height
            width: myList.width
            Text {
                id: txOption
                font.pointSize: 15
                text: option
            }
            states: [
                State {
                    name: 'details'; when: model.selected
                    PropertyChanges {target: txOption; color: "red" } //some property magic
                }
            ]

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    console.debug(index + " selected")
                    if (main.curSelectedIndex != -1)
                        dataModel.setProperty(main.curSelectedIndex, "selected", false)
                    main.curSelectedIndex = index
                    dataModel.setProperty(index, "selected", true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I like your approach. I was thinking about some form of inter-connection, but using QML a while seems that it's necessary to wrap your own mind around little different methods.

Comment: Now I'm thinking if it's possible in QML to dynamically attach component as signal handler from another one - as I was trying in the first place. If not then I'll also probably try to move your example to the next level: multiple views (ListViews, Grids, custom screens, etc) with multiple subviews and toolbar with back/forward buttons to browse between them. Some view stack comes to mind but I'll have to figure this out. Anyway I have no reason to brag and not accept your answer as it fits exactly what I was asking for :) Thank you sir once again!

Comment: Problem is that AFAIK, the there is no way to manipulate the delegate components from the outside